# Flat list to tree : handle bad links to make a valid one

Tags: python, recursion, tree

This is a working code for a well design flat list to obtain a tree :

```
 data = [('john','marry'),('mike','john'),('mike','hellen')('john','elisa')]

roots = set()
mapping = {}
for parent,child in data:
childitem = mapping.get(child,None)
if childitem is None:
    childitem =  {}
    mapping[child] = childitem
else:
    roots.discard(child)
parentitem = mapping.get(parent,None)
if parentitem is None:
    mapping[parent] = {child:childitem}
    roots.add(parent)
else:
    parentitem[child] = childitem

tree = {id : mapping[id] for id in roots}

print (tree)
```

Unfortunately, my flat list is sometimes swap, like this :

```
data = [('marry','john'),('john','mike'),('mike','hellen'),('john','elisa')]
```

So how can I make a recursive validation and swap 'lines' when it's needed for a known head and n child ?

Comment: Which should be the root of the data in the data list? What do you mean by `flat list is sometimes swap`, who does the swapping, when, and why?

Comment: Swap is when the parent is in the child column, like if the head of the tree is in the first column, the swap or switch is needed to have a valid tree. More, if 2 first child are in the parent column and the correct parent in the child column, both need to be inverted to have a valid tree.